# App Onedrive API usage statistics

Tags: onedrive

I have published an Android app that can use Onedrive amongst other cloud providers. Is there any way to find out how many users have connected my app to Onedrive and how many (REST) API calls my app is making on the users' behalf? FWIW: "View usage statistics" in the Microsoft Account Developer Center has never worked, always failing with "Sorry, something went wrong".

Comment: We don't have a way for you to access this information yet, but we're working on it. If you are interested please consider adding it to the [onedrive.uservoice.com](http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer) page under "developer".

Comment: I think this suggestion already exists with quite a few votes - please upvote: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6417922-file-download-statistics